# Firing off event when clicking on a dropdown option

Tags: javascript, forms, input, dropdown, keyword

I am creating a form with a dropdown menu and would like to have their respective keywords appear for each one of the trips within that menu when clicked (preferably underneath the input field, as you can see in my code below).

1. **.show** is set to display:none
2. Keywords would be within the paragraph tags

**HTML**

```
<label for="tour-select">Choose a tour
    <select name="tour" id="tour-select" required>
        <option value="landmarks"></option>
           <p class="landmarks show"></p>
        <option value="hidden-gems"></option>
           <p class="hidden-gems show"></p>
        <option value="diana">The Diana (5h)</option>
           <p class="diana show"></p>
    </select>
</label>
```

I have tried the following in **JS** but with no success so far. I am not completely sure whether I am targeting the option value in the wrong way or whether it is an issue of how I have structured my code.

```
let tourInput = document.querySelector("select[name=tour]");
    tourInput.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (e.target.value == "landmarks") {
            tourInput.querySelector(".landmarks").classList.remove("show");
        }
    })
```

Comment: Putting `<p>` elements inside a `<select>` is invalid.

Comment: Are you trying to show a sub menu when clicking on an option menu? If so, you'll want to user other HTML such us unordered list. The select tag is really just used for forms. However if you are ok with the keywords not showing up directly below it (maybe they render elsewhere on the page), you can store the keywords as data attributes. Then when you click, you can reference the event.target's dataset.

Comment: @David thank you, I forgot about that

Comment: @rguttersohn never mind, I found a way. I basically just moved the <p> tags outside of the select tag

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing single quotes around to selector name. Change `"select[name=tour]"` to `"select[name='tour']"`.